# Bash - find recursively in many directories

Tags: bash

I Have 2 or more directories path stored in a variable - 
output of a find command:

```
folders="$(find /g -type d -name "jpgtest*")"
```

Note: directory names may have spaces.

Assuming there are 2 directories: g/jpgtest1 , g/jpgtest2.

How do I search all subdirectories of those two for all files of the form "*.A",

and then remove all files in the form "*.B" where * means: name starts with the same name of files with extension A.

for example: found: g/jpgtest1/test1/j.A

Remove: g/jpgtest1/test1/j1.B , but don't remove g/jpgtest1/test1/f1.B

and so on for the 2 directories.

A possible solution:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in $folders/**/*.A ; do
   rm -f "${f%.A}"*.B
done
```

but it works only with one directory found in "folders", What should I change so it will work with several directories as well.

**EDIT:**

Any solution When it's in a bash script and the content of "folders" is unknown , say , as a result from finding folders older than one month:

```
  folders="$(find /g -maxdepth 1 -type d -atime +30)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following: suppose you find `jpgtest1` and `jpgtest2`. Then the expression `$folders/**/*.A` yields:

```
/g/jpgtest1 /g/jpgtest2/**/*.A
```

Which then expanded using glob, finding the `*.A` files only under `jpgtest2`. Try this:

```
for f in /g/**/jpgtest*/**/*.A ; do
```

If you intend to use the output of `find` as an input, you can do a double `for` for this reason:

```
for folder in $folders; do
   for f in $folder/**/*.A ; do
      rm -f "${f%.A}"*.B
   done
done
```

The only drawback of this is that it breaks if any folder has a whitespace in it. The solution is to read line-by-line (or use `IFS`, but I'm showing the line-by-line solution):

```
while read folder; do
   for f in "$folder"/**/*.A ; do
      rm -f "${f%.A}"*.B
   done
done < <(find /g -maxdepth 1 -type d -atime +30)
```

Comment: To be closer to OP's `find` command, it would be `/g/**/jpgtest*/**/*.A`.